# Iframe is not showing content inside of another Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, iframe

I have 4 google apps scripts as follow:


Script 1: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw5i_oLraK4iK9Ur6Z4Po3DpeiPkcw7TS7uXFf7EH2_Rz_dR1M/exec

It shows its content perfectly which are multiple options

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<style>
</style>

<body>
<div><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec">Option 1 of 1</a></div>
<div><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec">Option 2 of 1</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Script 2: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwJBNgV5oZaciuYnKHVBd364KntVhNRFGb5zYhB67e-09RgtJ0/exec

It has an Iframe that shows the content of script 1 with an option to return to all options existed in script 1 and it's working fine too

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<style>
</style>

<body>

<div class="item" onclick="theFunction()">Option 1</div>

<iframe id="iframe" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw5i_oLraK4iK9Ur6Z4Po3DpeiPkcw7TS7uXFf7EH2_Rz_dR1M/exec" style="border-width:0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="450px" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<script>
function theFunction() {
document.getElementById('iframe').src = document.getElementById('iframe').src
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Script 3: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyuxG9Hj22wR3_Xc8pC1TfZlXrDbaF2ReVJ5BkA52pfLNJOIr0/exec

It has many options where the first one opens script 2 and it's working fine as well

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<style>
</style>

<body>
<div><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwJBNgV5oZaciuYnKHVBd364KntVhNRFGb5zYhB67e-09RgtJ0/exec">Option 1</a></div>
<div><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec">Option 2</a></div>
<div><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec">Option 3</a></div>
<div><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec">Option 4</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem comes with script 4: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTPzr-I9Cg8sM9H7lDZxwbfs4d_03NjyQDiRh860g2T3xoBQVy/exec

It acts like script 2; it has an Iframe that shows the content of script 3 with an option to return to all options existed in script 3 but when I click the first option, it doesn't show the content of script 1


html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<style>
</style>

<body>

<div class="item" onclick="theFunction()">HOME</div>

<iframe id="iframe" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyuxG9Hj22wR3_Xc8pC1TfZlXrDbaF2ReVJ5BkA52pfLNJOIr0/exec" style="border-width:0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="305px" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<script>
function theFunction() {
document.getElementById('iframe').src = document.getElementById('iframe').src
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. thanks in advace

Comment: Have you done anything to debug? Any error messages on the browser console?

Comment: I have this error message from the console:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: a is null
    ph https://n-4mjj3uvneamhrqp4k7phmwceirebf42z73nnywi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2876748119-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ar.js:129
    E https://n-4mjj3uvneamhrqp4k7phmwceirebf42z73nnywi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2876748119-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ar.js:24

Comment: Jd https://n-4mjj3uvneamhrqp4k7phmwceirebf42z73nnywi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2876748119-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ar.js:55
    a https://n-4mjj3uvneamhrqp4k7phmwceirebf42z73nnywi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2876748119-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ar.js:53

Comment: I don't think those are relevant. Any specific error, when clicking option1 and waiting?

Comment: Nothing, if you can also check here please https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTPzr-I9Cg8sM9H7lDZxwbfs4d_03NjyQDiRh860g2T3xoBQVy/exec

Comment: When I open the 4th link, it shows the other scripts or options like in half, is that what you mean is not showing correctly?

Comment: Yes open the 4th link, then click option 1. Option 1 has two other sub-options (1 of 1 and 2 of 1) where they show up when you open the 2nd link directly but having the 2nd link as an Iframe inside the 4th link, it shows noting

Comment: I tried to search the problem and I think it has something to do with the base targeting in the head that allows the Iframe to be loaded inside another one but unfortunately I'm still trying to make it works. thanks all for help and support